# Сортировка выбором. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, сортировка

```js
function selSort(arr) {
    var tmp;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[arr.length - 1]) {
            tmp =  arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1];
            arr[arr.length - 1] = tmp;
        } 
    }
    return arr;
}
document.write(selSort([6, 9, 7, 8, 3, 5]))
```

Здравствуйте. Читал про сортировку выбором. Как понимаю, смысл алгоритма - проверять первый и последний элементы массива. Если первый элемент больше последнего - меняем их местами. В общем, я написал вот такой код, но вместо желанного [3,5,6,7,8,9] выдает [5,6,7,8,3,9]. Как исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Попробуйте вашим кодом отсортировать `[100500, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`. Станет более очевидно, что не так) Каждый раз как только натыкается на число, которое больше, чем последнее в массиве - меняет их местами. Как только доходит до наибольшего числа - все остальные после него не сортиируются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS в этом месте очень похож на C# из [википедийного решения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)

(нагло скопировал, поменяв `int` на `let`, `.Count` на `.length`):

```js
function sort(list) {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
    let min = i;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
      if (list[j] < list[min]) {
        min = j;
      }
    }
    let dummy = list[i];
    list[i] = list[min];
    list[min] = dummy;
    // Три строчки выше можно заменить на одну 
    // [list[i], list[min]] = [list[min], list[i]];
  }
  return list;
}

console.log( sort( [4, 7, 1, 5, 9, 0, 3, 2, 8, 6] ) )
```